# What should be the standard of class naming in SASS according to BEM? Should class name start with capital letter or small?

Tags: html, css, class, sass, bem

What should be the standard of class naming in SASS according to BEM? Should class name start with capital letter or small ?

Comment: You can check the BEM site for information like this - http://getbem.com/naming/

Answer (score 0):

In general, the class name starts with a small letter. Sass recommends using all lowercase letters with dashes for separation.
for example:
HTML

```
<nav class="c-menu c-menu--horizontal">
   <div class="c-menu__item c-menu__item--first">
    <span class="c-menu__link">Link 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="c-menu__item">
    <span class="c-menu__link">Link 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="c-menu__item menu__item--last">
    <span class="c-menu__link">Link 3</span>
  </div>
</nav>
SASS with BEM methodolody

.c-menu
  //...

  &__item
    // ..

  &__item--first
    // ..

  &__item--last
    // ..

  &__link
    // ..
```

.menu--horizontal
//...
.menu
&__item
//..

The c  from  .c-menu stands for component and it's a part of a namespacing technique that is very useful. See here for a nice article on this topic. All in all our HTML and CSS look decent but BEM shines when it's used with Sass.